# set up git alias, but then calling it gives 'command not found'

Tags: git, bash, alias

I want to set up an alias in git for counting the total lines in a repository, so I went into Git Bash and entered this:

```
git config --global alias.linecount 'ls-files -z | xargs -0 wc -l'
```

After I entered the command, there was no error message.  Then I entered

```
linecount
```

and got this error message:

```
sh: linecount: command not found
```

Is there a different way that I should be setting up an alias?

Comment: You set up a git alias, not a shell alias. You need to use git to run it. `git linecount`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing exclamation point (`!`).

From: `man git-config`:

> If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will be treated as a shell command.

You could do:

```
git config alias.linecount 'ls-files -z'
```

which would be an alias to `git` command, however since you're using shell syntax (like pipe), then all its parameters are interpreted by `git` it-self, so in this case you need to clarify that this should be treated as a shell command.

Here is sample git alias in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
  linecount =       !git ls-files -z | xargs -0 wc -l
```

From the command-line, the correct syntax would be:

```
git config alias.linecount '!git ls-files -z | xargs -0 wc -l'
```

<sup>Note: Adding `--global` is optional.</sup>

Then you call it by:

```
git linecount
```

Comment: After setting that alias, I run it with `git linecount` and get this error: `ls-files -z | xargs -0 wc -l: ls-files: command not found`

Comment: I can run `git ls-files` no problem.  But when I `git config` the alias as you posted, then `git linecount` gives that error.

Comment: Yes, that was it--the `!` was causing `ls-files` to be run as a shell command.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You set up a git alias, not a shell alias.

You need to use git to run it.

```
git linecount
```

You also need to use a shell-exec git alias if you expect to use shell features (like pipes).

```
git config --global alias.linecount '!git ls-files -z | xargs -0 wc -l'
```

Comment: Entering that gave me `unknown switch '0'` and then the help page for `git ls-files`.

Comment: Ah, true you are using a pipe which means you need a shell-exec git alias.