# Git does not find alias command

Tags: windows, git

I have a git alias working when I start the RStudio shell.

If I try to run the alias from a Windows command line, it says "... is not a git command".

In contrast to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221033/set-up-git-alias-but-then-calling-it-gives-command-not-found), it seems my `C:/Users/user/.gitconfig` is not found as it is not shown in `git config --list --show-origin`.

I guess, I have to reference to the file?

How can I do this on windows? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I guess, I have to reference to the file? "

You just need to set the `HOME` environment variable to `%USERPROFILE%`.
Git search for the global config file in `%HOME%` (which is not set by default on Windows).

You can find an example in "[Git for Windows tip: Setting `$HOME` and the startup directory](https://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/git-for-windows-tip-setting-home-and-the-startup-directory/)" from Daniel Lee.

[image: edit variable HOME]

Answer (score 1):

I'm recommending of reading this post to get a full understanding of what is alias and how to set it.

http://durdn.com/blog/2012/11/22/must-have-git-aliases-advanced-examples/

To answer directly: you need to have `.gitconfig` in your user directory or any other location which git looks in.

---

#### `.gitconfig` is collecting information in a commutative way:

- **`System level`** - (`--system`) - OS level
- **`User`** (`--global`) - The file will be placed under your %HOME% folder.
- **`Project`** (`--local`) - Specific definitions for the given project. This file is located in `.git/config`

Comment: Thank you for the explanations but VonC's solution worked for me. So you can have your .gitconfig anywhere - you just have to refernce to it.